# How to Upgrade to dojo 1.10 inside <div> tag?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Anyone knows how can I upgrade the following line of dojo code? The problem is in dijit.popoup.close() that the dijit/popup.close() which is the upgraded of it doesn't work there

```
    var findContent = "<div class='findTTheader' ><span class='findTTheaderLabel'>Find " + curMapLyr.layerInfos[layerID].name + "</span><img class='closeToolTip' src='../genCode/images/Close16.png' onclick='dijit.popup.close()'></div>";
```

Comment: You can't, because Dojo 2.x hasn't been released.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the latest version which is 1.10. As I read in the dojo website, this is an update which is gonna soon be released in dojo 2.x as well, and 2.x won't be compatible with any 1.x as soon as it is released, which will cause the code not to work in any upgraded applications/OS such as iOS updates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not actually sure where to download a copy of Dojo 2.0 to test this, but I think one of these will work for you:

First up, try the "stupid version":

```
onclick="require('dijit/popup').close()"
```

If that doesn't work, then you'll have to add the click handler in JavaScript rather than HTML - so render your div without any `onclick` attribute, and then do something like this in JS:

```
require(['dojo/query', 'dijit/popup'], function (query, popup) {
  query('img.closeToolTip').on('click', function() {
    popup.close()
  });
})
```

That's might not be exactly correct syntax, but it should give you the idea.

Update - this variation might actually work better than the above. Try it out and let me know:

```
require(['dojo/query', 'dijit/popup'], function (query, popup) {
  query('img.closeToolTip').on('click', popup.close);
})
```

Comment: The second one works but very occasionally. It is  so weird that it works for some of the TooltipDialog objects in which I've used findContent...Is it possible that I'm missing some kinda ready function? And sorry, by dojo 2.x I meant the latest update of dojo which is 1.10

Comment: and another issue is: it works in Windows/Chrome but does not in iOS8.1/Chrome

Comment: It's probably a timing thing introduced by the `require([...` stuff, which would explain why it works sometimes and not others. Without seeing the rest of your code, though, I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: I just had to place the query closer to the div definition. Thank you for your great answer!